# Camera movement in Super Hexagon

Tags: rotation, opengl-es2

I do realize there is no camera in OpenGL ES 2, but from my understanding you can simulate one using view and projection matrices. I'm using Android, by the way. Here's a video of the game, in case you are not familiar with it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mDjFdetU28

I am trying to understand how the world/camera is rotated and tilted. Is that done purely by rotating and tilting the view matrix? So you'd have a `tilt` and `rotationSpeed` fields that you'd use each frame in something like `rotate(viewMatrix, angle + rotationSpeed)` followed by `rotate(viewMatrix, tilt)`? How would you achieve a similar effect?

Comment: What makes you think it's a camera at all? I'd say it's just polygons being translated/rotated/scaled.

Comment: @Byte56 The fact that all polygons need to be rotated and tilted by the same angle. Surely it would be easier to rotate just the camera rather than every single block in the game.